# Загрузил на хост скрипт, настроил, но нет раздела

Tags: dle, data-life-engine

Установил один скрипт, понадобилось подключить сторонний модуль, но раздела "сторонний модуль" нет! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Версия DLE- 11.3

Answer (score 0):

Видимо нужен раздел "Плагины", раздел "Сторонние модули" появиться после установки дополнительного модуля.